# Passing unknown args and kwargs to function in python

Tags: python

I have an object that takes in a function name func, args, and kwargs, and at some point runs

```
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

The issue is, if func requires no args/kwargs, args/kwargs default to None, which leads to a TypeError. For example, if the function required no parameters, args, kwargs default to None:

```
def test():
    pass

args = None

kwargs = None

test(*args, **kwargs)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b9618694fbf2> in <module>()
----> 1 test(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: test() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

I'm sure there's a good way to solve this without cascading if statements checking if args/kwargs exist, each with its own function call, but I'm not sure how. The main goal is to pass a function, and its unknown parameters to an object, which will then use them in a method later.

Edited: added an example for clarity

Comment: What do you mean with "Python doesn't like that"? Does it throw an exception? Can you write your cascading if statements here and we can help to improve them!

Comment: args and kwargs will be empty but not `None` if no arguments are provided when calling the function. Are you referring to a specific keyword argument instead? If so, you can always do `kwargs.get('myarg', 'default_value')`?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Added some edits to help. I have a class that runs an arbitrary function with unknown parameters that are passed on initialization. Just trying to figure out the best way to store these and then run the function later on as part of a class method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The issue is, if func requires no args/kwargs, args/kwargs default to None, which leads to a TypeError.

This is not true:

```
def func1(*args, **kwargs)
    print args, kwargs
```

will print

```
() {}
```

In reverse,

```
def func2(): pass
```

can be perfectly called with

```
func2(*(), **{})
```

So just change your `args` and `kwargs` variables and you're fine.

Comment: Ah, knew there was a better way to do this. I was passing in args/kwargs to the class as kwargs themselves (silly in retrospect), and setting them to None as default. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid to default your `args` and `kwargs` to `None`.

- `args` should be a tuple : `args = ()`
- `kwargs` should be a dictionnary : `kwargs = {}`